# CVS Server 1.12.13 (client/server) can not start up after upgrade Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: macos, upgrade, cvs

it worked very well in Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

but after upgrade to Yosemite, it can't auto start up now.

cvs version

```
Home-CentermatoMacBook:~ homecenter$ cvs -v
Concurrent Versions System (CVS) 1.12.13 (client/server)

which cvs
/usr/local/bin/cvs

ls -l /usr/local/bin/cvs
lrwxr-xr-x  1 homecenter  admin  29 May  6 11:30 /usr/local/bin/cvs -> ../Cellar/cvs/1.12.13/bin/cvs

ls -l /Library/LaunchDaemons/cvspserver.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  827 Oct 23 11:04 /Library/LaunchDaemons/cvspserver.plist
```

the cvspserver.plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>com.apple.cvspserver</string>
 <key>UserName</key>
 <string>cvs</string>
 <key>Program</key>
 <string>/usr/local/bin/cvs</string>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
 <string>/usr/local/bin/cvs</string>
 <string>-f</string>
 <string>--allow-root=/extdisk/testcvs</string>
 <string>pserver</string>
 </array>
 <key>Sockets</key>
 <dict>
 <key>Listeners</key>
 <dict>
 <key>SockPassive</key>
 <true/>
 <key>SockServiceName</key>
 <string>cvspserver</string>
 <key>SockType</key>
 <string>SOCK_STREAM</string>
 </dict>
 </dict>
 <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
 <dict>
 <key>Wait</key>
 <false/>
 </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

user account cvs (username in cvspserver.plist) works well.

it is also no effect :

```
sudo cvs -f --allow-root=/extdisk/testcvs/ pserver
```

I had also updated the "Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10) ver:6.1" and upgrade Xcode to 6.1

Help

Answer (score 1):

change SockServerName and SockType as following:

```
             <key>SockServiceName</key>
             <string>2401</string>
             <key>SockType</key>
             <string>stream</string>
```

now it works well.

more launchctl man doc, please refer : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist

Comment: thanks!  I verified that the only critical change was to change "SOCK_STREAM" to "stream".    Then you can do the standard telnet test:  `telnet localhost 2401` to verify that pserver is running.  (problem encountered when upgrading from mt lion to el capitan).

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem with the CVS Service because I set the "KeepAlive" flag to "true", which isn't acceptable in OS X Yosemite.

The SockServiceName can pretty have the value "cvspserver" as long as the file "/etc/services" contains the following lines:

cvspserver      2401/udp    # cvspserver

cvspserver      2401/tcp    # cvspserver